# How to run specific groups in tesng.xml using ant?

Tags: xml, ant, testng

i have to run test according to groups in testng.xml. 
and which test group has to include want to give using ant.

For eg.

```
<test name="Test1" preserve-order="true">
<groups>
<run>
<include name="Group1"/>
<include name="Group2"/>
</run>
</groups>
</test>
```

Here i want to give input Group1 then only Group1 should run.

How to achive this? please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [TestNG Ant plugin,](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html) you can specify the groups directly as an attribute:

> groups :  The list of groups to run, separated by spaces or commas.

Comment: Thanks for reply

But it will create another testng.xml

suppose if i want to run "Group1" then it will auto generate testng.xml for Group1

but i want to use existing testng.xml